# How long should I give pectic enzyme to takle hazy finished fruit wine?

Tags: wine, pectic-enzyme, fruit-wine

I've got a gallon of really sweet, 16.5% kiwi wine. The fermentation has not been completely stopped but haze didn't settle with time or after I used fining agent. A quick test with methylated spirit confirmed I am dealing with pectin haze.

I'm planning to throw in a pectolase solution to my wine to break down pectin. I'm not sure how long I should let it sit before the enzyme has done it's job. Is it more like hours, days or weeks? Is if going to be obvious that the process has finished (i.e. will the broken down pectin then precipitate and settle down as sediment) or will I have to eyeball it and hit it with more fining agents later?

Answer (score 1):

I only have experience with cider (and many thousands of gallons of grape wine, but it's not a problem with grapes). I put the enzyme in when I crushed the fruit (I suggest you do this next time) and it cleared very quickly in the secondary. It is usally less than a month. I suggest you wait a month or two, wine is about waiting, it's not beer. Gelatin could also work to settle a haze quickly. It sounds like it's not done fermenting either, which is going to continue to be a problem. When you start getting over 16%, fermentation can be sluggish and stall and/or never really finish.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I now know that the enzyme should go in before the fermentation but I have just realised that my text had a typo in it which made it say that the fermentation "has not been stopped" instead that it "has *now* been stopped" which is the actual case, in which your answer doesn't apply. I'm sorry!

Comment: Thanks I hardly need to the points. Just put the enzymes in at the beginning. But I did answer your question. Once you put them in, it should take a few weeks to completely clear. If you want it clear sooner, put in some Gelatin but that is less gentle. Even better buy a filter.

Comment: Yes, but my point was that my question wasn't about beginning of the fermentation but a situation where I'm putting in the enzymes into an already finished wine. I mean, I can't just go back in time and decide to put them in at the beginning, can I?

Answer (score 1):

I would give it a coulpe of weeks, if it has not cleared after 2 weeks I would add a second dose of pectalase as there is a chance the alcohol will have deactivated the enzyme. Regarding quantity to add follow the manufacture's guidlines.

If still not clear, either bottle and drink cloudly or try adding some finings wait a week then bottle.

Answer (score 1):

Alcohol inhibits pectic enzyme.  At around 16% you have some issues.  Double the dose (of enzyme) and maybe double the time to clear, maybe 2-3 months.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a matter of how long, more of how much. My "Winemaker's recipe handbook" c. 1976 does not have kiwi.  You may try a web search.

I'll list some examples from the book. All for 1-gallon recipes. You need this ingredient if your fruit has "pectin" in it.

I did some additional digging with a few pectin definitions:

Pectin is a type of carbohydrate -- specifically a polysaccharide -- that’s found in the cell walls of plants, especially the leaves, roots, and fruits. It acts mainly to bind plant cells together. Pectin content varies widely among plants and even within the same plant over time. In general, pectin is broken down by enzymes as the fruit ripens and becomes softer. Pectin and other dietary fibers do not contribute significantly to nutrition -- primarily because your intestines can’t digest them very well -- but they do contribute to health. Pectin consumption impacts blood cholesterol levels and it helps regulates blood glucose levels. It also helps remove toxins such as lead and mercury from your body.

A number of other fruits are very good sources of pectin -- assuming you eat them with their skin -- and these include all berries, peaches, apricots, cherries, and grapes. Berries particularly notable for their pectin content include strawberries, blackberries, raspberries, and dewberries. Bananas are also a good source, especially if you don’t let them get too ripe or soft before eating them.

I also checked kiwi jelly recipes, no pectin's added. (assumption, kiwi high in pectin)

back to wine recipes

Recipe Name, Amount of Fruit, Peptic Enzyme amount

Gooseberry, 2.5lb, .5tsp
Currant, 2.5-3.5lb, .5tsp
Elderberry, 3lb, NONE
Banana, 3lb, NONE
Apple, 8-16lb, .5tsp
Peach & Apricot, 2.5lb, 1tsp
Black Rasp Blue - berry, 4-3-2lb, all .5tsp
Grapes, any, NONE
Mellon & Orange, any, NONE
Pear & Persimmon 3-4lb, .5tsp
Pumpkin - Rhubarb - rice, 4-4-2, NONE

Berries, berries, berries, a few pounds, .5tsp
That's a sample of the 101 recipes. 
Good luck, I'd guess 3lb, .5tsp.  Have to try.